# Oracle EBS R12.2.6 JSP page call not happening properly

Tags: javascript, java, oracle, jsp, oracle-ebs

in EBS 11i Instance there a Form Function 'CustomForm' - its WEB HTML call is defined as below

> javascript:void window.open('OA_HTML/jsp/pol/log/xxcustom.jsp?xx_resp_id=
>   [RESPONSIBILITY_ID]')   --- this works fine in Oracle EBS 11i

so when we click the MENU associated with 'CustomForm' , xxcustom.jsp appears in new browser page and in that URL [RESPONSIBILITY_ID] is replaced with actual responsibility id value as shown below

```
http://isy900.bas.com:8042/OA_HTML/jsp/pol/log/xxcustom.jsp?xx_resp_id=12345'
```

but when i implement the same in R12.2.6 (Since I am working for 11i to R12 re-implementation) in the page URL

```
http://isy900.bas.com:8042/OA_HTML/jsp/pol/log/xxcustom.jsp?xx_resp_id=[RESPONSIBILITY_ID] ---Note the value is not appearing
```

How to achieve the same functionality in EBS R12.2.6 ?

Comment: Can you post your code pls?

Comment: can you print `strRespId` please

Comment: yes.. I already tested that..  when I printed it gives [RESPONSIBILITY_ID]

Comment: Posting your oracle function code (not only the url part), would be helpful...

Comment: Yes... the code I have posted up there... Actually the moment we click the link.. in the page URL  we should be able to see the actual Responsibility ID. But here its not happening...

Comment: I completely rephrased the question.. this is the actual issue.