# HTML call - Not sure what the URL is calling

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

In Oracle - form function (is to call a JSP page is as below)

I am trying to understand what the **xxpo_responsibilityId** could be in the below context , like is it just a name or a function or something else which is already defined somewhere - Pls help me to understand

> javascript:void window.open('/OA_HTML/jsp/calendar.jsp?xxpo_responsibilityID
>   =[RESPONSIBILITY_ID]')

can someone help me in understanding the portion after the Question mark '?' from the above stament

Comment: This is called a parameter. The name of the parameter is `xxpo_responsibilityID`, the value is some other value stored in in a variable called `[RESPONSIBILITY_ID]`. This is all done by Oracle form function design, I believe it's the way they pass information to the page (in this case I suppose it's a calendar).

Comment: thank you for your answer.. Actually this question is a follow up of another question which I asked. Any Idea where there parameters are defined ? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43423209/oracle-ebs-r12-2-6-jsp-page-call-not-happening-properly

Answer (score -1):

***xxpo_responsibilityID*** is the variable

***[RESPONSIBILITY_ID]*** is the value of *xxpo_responsibilityID*

Comment: so in the place of xxpo_responsibilityID we can place any thing .. and need not to be defined anywhere right ?

Comment: no. xxpo_responsibilityID is used as variable (query string) in calendar.jsp. You can put any value on [RESPONSIBILITY_ID], provided it falls within the definition (context).

Comment: You'll most likely break things if you replace `xxpo_responsibilityID` with anything else, and the form function will not be able to perform as it should. This is done by Oracle, and you don't need to define it.